# Resizing SDL OpenGL window

Tags: opengl, resize, window, sdl

When I issue `glViewport` with my new resolution it does not seem to update the size of the (front and back) framebuffer. My FBO's seem to handle the resize just fine because I just re-create my FBO texture with the new size.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this sort of thing simply not supported on Linux? I'm trying to avoid calling `SDL_SetVideoMode` so I can hold on to my OpenGL context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glViewport` does not affect the size of the window. Indeed, no OpenGL command can change the windows size. All `glViewport` does is change the transform from normalized device coordinate space to window space. It effectively changes what *part* of the window you render to, not the size of the window itself.

The size of the window is managed by whatever system created the window. If SDL doesn't have a function to change the window's size, then the window's size cannot be changed.

Comment: So on Linux why does the framebuffer not update? Is this a problem with SDL? On Linux it still only renders to the left 800 pixels (my initial size is 800x600, but on windows it is able to draw to the entire window)

Comment: @StevenLu: Because glViewport doesn't change the framebuffer size. It selects the part of the framebuffer the projection should map to. It won't even set proper clipping, you need glScissor for that.